# Is this partition axiom equivalent to axiom of choice over ZF?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Suppose we add the axiom to ZF that for any set $S$, and any partition $P$ of $S$, the cardinality of $P$ is less than or equal to the cardinality of $S$. It is known that the axiom of choice implies that axiom. My question is, is the converse true? Or are there models of ZF where that axiom holds but the axiom of choice doesn't?

Comment: The converse appears to be essentially the [partition principle](http://karagila.org/tags/partition-principle/), and whether it implies the axiom of choice is an open problem.

Comment: I mean, I close this as a duplicate about once a month. It is **literally** the most recent question under the [axiom-of-choice] tag at the time you are writing this question!